# Android App and Blue Screen

Tags: android, eclipse

I want your help, I created an android application it was working well on device with Android version 2.2.2 when I installed the app on other device with Android version 2.3.6 when I restart it, it randomly gets blue screen and to end this situation I have to remove the battery and put it again.

logcat:

```
09-18 14:55:22.746: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): hwcomposer module not found
09-18 14:55:22.845: E/Trace(36): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:55:24.155: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:55:24.325: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:55:25.015: E/Trace(89): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:55:35.544: E/BandwidthController(33): runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists res=256
09-18 14:55:35.624: E/BandwidthController(33): runIptablesCmd(): failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists res=256
09-18 14:55:35.634: E/Netd(33): Unable to bind netlink socket: No such file or directory
09-18 14:55:35.634: E/Netd(33): Unable to open quota2 logging socket
09-18 14:56:45.384: E/BatteryService(294): acOnlinePath not found
09-18 14:56:45.414: E/BatteryService(294): usbOnlinePath not found
09-18 14:56:45.414: E/BatteryService(294): wirelessOnlinePath not found
09-18 14:56:45.414: E/BatteryService(294): batteryStatusPath not found
09-18 14:56:45.414: E/BatteryService(294): batteryHealthPath not found
09-18 14:56:45.424: E/BatteryService(294): batteryPresentPath not found
09-18 14:56:45.424: E/BatteryService(294): batteryCapacityPath not found
09-18 14:56:45.424: E/BatteryService(294): batteryVoltagePath not found
09-18 14:56:45.424: E/BatteryService(294): batteryTemperaturePath not found
09-18 14:56:45.424: E/BatteryService(294): batteryTechnologyPath not found
09-18 14:56:46.054: E/PowerManagerService-JNI(294): Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
09-18 14:56:47.224: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:57:10.734: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
09-18 14:57:10.854: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
09-18 14:57:12.244: E/EventHub(294): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
09-18 14:57:12.254: E/EventHub(294): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
09-18 14:57:12.994: E/Trace(294): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:57:14.694: E/VoldConnector(294): NDC Command {1 volume list} took too long (673ms)
09-18 14:57:18.234: E/CommandListener(33): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
09-18 14:57:18.284: E/WifiStateMachine(294): Failed to disable IPv6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1 interface ipv6 wlan0 disable' failed with '400 1 Failed to change IPv6 state (No such file or directory)'
09-18 14:57:18.535: E/MobileDataStateTracker(294): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
09-18 14:57:18.535: E/MobileDataStateTracker(294): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
09-18 14:57:27.325: E/NetdConnector(294): NDC Command {2 firewall disable} took too long (513ms)
09-18 14:57:29.565: E/Trace(353): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:57:36.714: E/Trace(381): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:57:36.714: E/ThrottleService(294): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-18 14:57:40.424: E/Trace(400): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:57:43.724: E/Trace(411): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:57:46.704: E/BluetoothAdapter(353): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:57:46.704: E/BluetoothAdapter(353): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:57:50.395: E/BluetoothAdapter(353): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:57:50.415: E/ActivityThread(381): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
09-18 14:57:50.485: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(381): Could not find a dictionary pack
09-18 14:57:51.945: E/Trace(438): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:57:52.275: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:57:52.605: E/LocationManagerService(294): no geocoder provider found
09-18 14:57:55.914: E/Trace(451): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:58:11.154: E/BluetoothAdapter(353): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:14.325: E/Trace(485): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:58:16.444: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:58:17.125: E/BluetoothAdapter(400): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:22.874: E/UserHistoryDictionary(381): when loading: file not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin/files/UserHistoryDictionary.en_US.dict: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-18 14:58:23.246: E/BluetoothAdapter(400): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:24.125: E/BluetoothAdapter(353): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:412)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:428)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:979)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionaryGetter.loadFallbackResource(BinaryDictionaryGetter.java:183)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionaryGetter.getDictionaryFiles(BinaryDictionaryGetter.java:456)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryFactory.createMainDictionaryFromManager(DictionaryFactory.java:57)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryFactory.createMainDictionaryFromManager(DictionaryFactory.java:87)
09-18 14:58:25.364: E/StrictMode(381):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.Suggest$1.run(Suggest.java:108)
09-18 14:58:25.376: E/Trace(507): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:58:28.024: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.034: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.044: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.054: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.124: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.264: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.314: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.394: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
09-18 14:58:28.474: E/SoundPool(294): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
09-18 14:58:29.704: E/BluetoothAdapter(294): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:29.724: E/BluetoothAdapter(294): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:35.354: E/dalvikvm(381): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
09-18 14:58:35.684: E/Trace(534): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294): ANR in com.android.systemui
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294): Reason: Executing service com.android.systemui/.ImageWallpaper
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294): Load: 8.02 / 2.83 / 1.05
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294): CPU usage from 1ms to 41008ms later with 99% awake:
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   32% 36/surfaceflinger: 28% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 6 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   22% 294/system_server: 16% user + 5.8% kernel / faults: 5393 minor 6 major
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   7.6% 411/com.android.launcher: 6.1% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 3729 minor 3 major
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   6.7% 89/bootanimation: 6% user + 0.7% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   5.2% 451/android.process.acore: 3.6% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 3094 minor 16 major
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   3.3% 400/com.android.phone: 2.5% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 1570 minor 5 major
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   3.2% 353/com.android.systemui: 2.5% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 888 minor 1 major
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   3.1% 47/adbd: 0.1% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 31 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   1.2% 37/zygote: 1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 282 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.9% 381/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0.6% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 660 minor 1 major
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.4% 438/com.android.location.fused: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 400 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.2% 291/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.1% 39/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.1% 30/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0% 35/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   0% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 473/sh: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 475/app_process: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 485/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 507/com.android.music: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 534/<pre-initialized>: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294): 99% TOTAL: 77% user + 21% kernel + 0.1% irq + 0.5% softirq
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294): CPU usage from 34091ms to 37532ms later:
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   37% 36/surfaceflinger: 32% user + 5.7% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     31% 73/SurfaceFlinger: 28% user + 2.7% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.5% 86/EventThread: 0.3% user + 1.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.2% 83/VSyncThread: 0.3% user + 0.9% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 87/Binder_1: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 148/Binder_2: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 466/Binder_3: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 36/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   27% 294/system_server: 16% user + 10% kernel / faults: 633 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     7.9% 309/UI: 6% user + 1.8% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     6.3% 311/ActivityManager: 2.3% user + 3.9% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     4.7% 301/Compiler: 2.3% user + 2.3% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     2.6% 426/Binder_3: 2.1% user + 0.5% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.3% 308/er.ServerThread: 0.5% user + 0.7% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.3% 348/AudioService: 1% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1% 430/Binder_4: 1% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 306/Binder_2: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 320/PowerManagerSer: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 435/Binder_5: 0.5% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 294/system_server: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 305/Binder_1: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 310/WindowManager: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 347/SyncHandlerThre: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 436/Binder_6: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 471/Binder_7: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 519/Binder_8: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):    +0% 529/Thread-73: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   8.9% 411/com.android.launcher: 5.8% user + 3% kernel / faults: 633 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     3.5% 411/ndroid.launcher: 2.3% user + 1.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     2.3% 462/launcher-loader: 1.2% user + 1% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     2% 412/GC: 1.7% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1% 418/Compiler: 0.7% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 420/FinalizerDaemon: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   6.4% 89/bootanimation: 5.2% user + 1.1% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     7% 104/BootAnimation: 5.8% user + 1.1% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   5% 400/com.android.phone: 3% user + 2% kernel / faults: 80 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     2.5% 400/m.android.phone: 1.7% user + 0.7% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.5% 407/Compiler: 0.7% user + 0.7% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 422/Binder_1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 423/Binder_2: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   3.9% 451/android.process.acore: 3.6% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 47 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     3.9% 465/Binder_2: 3.6% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.4% 458/Compiler: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 451/d.process.acore: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.2% 499/ApplicationsPro: 0.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   2% 47/adbd: 0.5% user + 1.4% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.1% 47/adbd: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.1% 280/adbd: 0.2% user + 0.8% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.5% 281/adbd: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):   1.7% 507/com.android.music: 0.2% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 212 minor
09-18 14:58:35.794: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.8% 
09-18 14:58:43.185: E/Trace(547): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:58:48.634: E/BluetoothAdapter(547): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:58:52.724: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:59:03.297: E/Trace(580): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:06.324: E/ThrottleService(294): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294): ANR in com.android.music
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294): Reason: Executing service com.android.music/.MediaPlaybackService
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294): Load: 14.26 / 4.94 / 1.82
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294): CPU usage from 2264ms to -19971ms ago:
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   38% 294/system_server: 26% user + 12% kernel / faults: 1529 minor 1 major
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   21% 36/surfaceflinger: 18% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 1503 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   11% 411/com.android.launcher: 8.6% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 1931 minor 3 major
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   10% 400/com.android.phone: 7.6% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 1037 minor 5 major
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   1.1% 47/adbd: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.7% 507/com.android.music: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 306 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   1% 534/android.process.media: 0.4% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 178 minor 4 major
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.8% 547/com.android.settings: 0.5% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 367 minor 1 major
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.4% 35/rild: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.4% 381/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 8 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.2% 1//init: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.2% 39/mediaserver: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.3% 291/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.3% 451/android.process.acore: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.1% 37/zygote: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 117 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.1% 485/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 30 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0% 438/com.android.location.fused: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0% 30/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0% 33/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 580/com.android.contacts: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):  +0% 602/com.android.mms: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294): 100% TOTAL: 71% user + 28% kernel + 0.1% irq + 0.3% softirq
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294): CPU usage from 14028ms to 17323ms later:
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   46% 294/system_server: 27% user + 18% kernel / faults: 240 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     12% 309/UI: 11% user + 0.9% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     10% 311/ActivityManager: 4.2% user + 5.8% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     9% 310/WindowManager: 6.7% user + 2.2% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     6.7% 552/Error dump: sys: 1.6% user + 5.1% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     6.4% 301/Compiler: 3.5% user + 2.9% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 568/Binder_9: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 294/system_server: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 305/Binder_1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 307/SensorService: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 308/er.ServerThread: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 320/PowerManagerSer: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 325/er$SensorThread: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 326/InputDispatcher: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 430/Binder_4: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 435/Binder_5: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 436/Binder_6: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 471/Binder_7: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 569/Binder_A: 0.3% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):    +0% 595/KeyguardWidgetP: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   12% 36/surfaceflinger: 10% user + 2.1% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     10% 73/SurfaceFlinger: 9.9% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 83/VSyncThread: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 148/Binder_2: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 36/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 86/EventThread: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 87/Binder_1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 466/Binder_3: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   14% 411/com.android.launcher: 13% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 165 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     6.8% 411/ndroid.launcher: 6.8% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     4% 412/GC: 4% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   11% 400/com.android.phone: 7.6% user + 3.6% kernel / faults: 199 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     7.6% 400/m.android.phone: 4.4% user + 3.2% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     2.8% 407/Compiler: 2.4% user + 0.4% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     1.2% 401/GC: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   8.9% 580/com.android.contacts: 2.5% user + 6.3% kernel / faults: 566 minor 18 major
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     6.8% 580/ndroid.contacts: 1.7% user + 5.1% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.8% 587/Compiler: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.4% 593/Binder_1: 0.4% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):    +0% 597/AsyncTask #1: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):    +0% 599/IntentService[C: 0% user + 0% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.9% 47/adbd: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 47/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 280/adbd: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 281/adbd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.6% 35/rild: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.6% 61/rild: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.3% 64/rild: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):   0.8% 534/android.process.media: 0.8% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
09-18 14:59:09.954: E/ActivityManager(294):     0.4% 534/d.process.media: 0.4% user + 0% 
09-18 14:59:10.485: E/Trace(602): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:16.184: E/JavaBinder(294): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-18 14:59:20.446: E/JavaBinder(294): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-18 14:59:20.474: E/JavaBinder(294): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-18 14:59:23.084: E/JavaBinder(294): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-18 14:59:24.935: E/JavaBinder(294): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-18 14:59:25.264: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:59:29.614: E/Trace(638): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:34.554: E/Trace(654): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:36.774: E/Trace(668): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:38.574: E/BluetoothAdapter(654): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:59:38.574: E/BluetoothAdapter(654): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:59:38.864: E/BluetoothAdapter(654): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:59:39.524: E/BluetoothAdapter(654): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:59:40.394: E/BluetoothAdapter(654): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:59:40.814: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:59:47.164: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-18 14:59:51.125: E/Trace(695): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:53.215: E/Trace(713): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-18 14:59:54.615: E/BluetoothAdapter(547): Bluetooth binder is null
09-18 14:59:57.498: E/BluetoothAdapter(547): Bluetooth binder is null
```

Any Help??

Thanks

Comment: You will need to post relevant code, and the logcat of the issue. Otherwise we have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: ok i'll edit the Post,

Comment: this is unreadable!! so many errors, hard to find anything there

Comment: i don't know it was working well but on the new device not :(